# Distribution of a transformation of the Dirichlet process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, nonparametric-statistics

Consider a Dirichlet process $P \sim \operatorname{DP}(\alpha)$ on $(X,\mathcal{X})$ and a measurable $\psi : X \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. We know then that:

$$ P \circ \psi^{-1} \sim \operatorname{DP}(\alpha \circ \psi^{-1})$$

However does there exist a relation of this type also for $\int \psi  dP$? In other words, can we express the distribution of $\int \psi  dP$ in terms of the Dirichlet process as it happens  for $P \circ \psi^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random Dirichlet measure $P$ is purely atomic and is
$$P(dw)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\delta_{X_k}(dw)Y_k\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(1-Y_j)$$ where $X_k$ and $Y_j$ are all independent such that the density of $Y_j$ in $(0,1)$  is $a(1-y)^{a-1}$ where $a$ is the mass of the finite measure $\alpha$ and such that the law on $X_k$ on $\Omega$ is $\alpha/a.$ As  a consequence
$$\int_{\Omega}\Psi(w)P(dw)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Psi(X_k)Y_k(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(1-Y_j)).$$